# Inverse of Interpreter["Color"]: Convert a RGBColor to a natural language color name

Tags: color, machine-learning, interpreter

What is the best way to create the inverse function of [`Interpreter["Color"]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/interpreter/Color.html)? That function takes a natural language color name like `"blue"` as input, and returns an `RGBColor` as output.

Here I whipped up a basic classifier based on Mathematica's built-in color symbols:

```
trainingset = 
  (List @@ ColorConvert[Symbol@#, "RGB"] -> #) & /@ 
  StringSplit[
    "Red,Green,Blue,Black,White,Gray,Cyan,Magenta,Yellow,Brown,Orange,Pink,Purple", ","]

testset = {
  RGBColor[0., 0., 0., 0.],         RGBColor[0., 0., 0., 1.], 
  RGBColor[0., 0.2196, 0.7215, 1.], RGBColor[0., 0.4235, 0.2078, 1.], 
  RGBColor[0., 0.4784, 0.2392, 1.], RGBColor[0.8078, 0.0666, 0.1490, 1.],
  RGBColor[1., 1., 1., 1.],         RGBColor[1., 0.8705, 0., 1.],
  RGBColor[0.2039, 0.6980, 0.2, 1.],RGBColor[0.0039, 0., 0.4, 1.]
}

c = Classify[trainingset]

c /@ Take[#, 3] & /@ (List @@ ColorConvert[#, "RGB"] & /@ testset)

(*
  {"Black", "Black", "Blue", "Black", "Green", "Red", "White", "Yellow", "Green", "Black"}
*)
```

I'm not sure how well it works in general, but the darker colors seem to come out as `"Black"`.

Comment: I am reminded of the xkcd color survey... anyway, maybe the new `ColorDistance[]` function could be useful here?

Comment: Please explain how the question is unclear, close voters.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand the close votes; the question looks pretty straightforward...

Comment: This seems not so much a coding question as 'where do i get an appropriate training set'.  Do you want to distill the answer down to a handful of basic colors (how many?), or do you want to feed it thousands of examples and likely get answers like "Crayola PinkSherbert". For the record I didn't downvote and I do think whoever did ought to explain.

Comment: The `Interpreter["StructuredColor"]` seems like a simple wrapper around the built-in (offline) `ColorData["Named"]` lists, which one can easily extract to make an inverse function. But, `Interpreter["Color"]` requires connectivity, and uses a different data set: `Interpreter["Color"]["sea green"] -> RGBColor[0.18…, 0.54…, 0.34…]` vs. `ColorData["Crayola"]["SeaGreen"] -> RGBColor[0.62…, 0.88…, 0.74…]`.

Comment: `Interpreter` seems to give the `ColorData["HTML"]["SeaGreen"]` result..

Comment: Oops! Still, I think it knows more colors than the `"Named"` sets: `Interpreter["Color"] /@ {"amaranth","bronze","blond"}` for example.

Comment: I'll try to find and process a corpus of named colors with `TextCases[#, "Color"]&` a bit later.

Answer (score 6):

This could provide a good starting point:

First step is to provide multiple examples of "red", "blue", etc for the training set.  I found a site that had some convenient images for this task.  For example a good sample of "reds":

[image]

So I import the images:

```
images = Import[
   "http://ingridsundberg.com/2014/02/04/the-color-thesaurus/", 
   "Images"][[2 ;; 13]];
```

assign some labels:

```
names = {"white", "tan", "yellow", "orange", "red", "pink", "purple", 
         "blue", "green", "brown", "gray", "black"}
```

pull out the ["dominant"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DominantColors.html) colors:

```
colors=DominantColors[#, 20, ColorCoverage -> 1/30, MinColorDistance -> 0] & /@ images;
```

and then train (but first I remove the `RGBColor` head as I had some difficulties passing `RGBColor[r,g,b]` directly to Classify)

```
training = Apply[List,colors,2];
cf = Classify[<|Thread[names -> training]|>];
```

from there I get some decent results:

```
cf[List @@ Brown]
(* "brown" *)

cf[List @@ Orange]
(* "orange" *)

cf[{0.1, 0.25, 0}]
(* "green" *)

Manipulate[cf[List @@ color], {color, Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: It feels strange to arbitrarily trust Ingrid Sundberg. (For example, who knows how long these URLs will work?) Why not use built-in Wolfram data? I think `ColorData[#][[3, 1]] & /@ {"HTML", "Crayola"}` could be useful.

Comment: @hftf, this is meant to provide a start, not a complete solution.  The general idea should be pretty much the same.

Comment: What I mean is, how are Ingrid Sundberg's color names going to get the domain of the `Interpreter["Color"]` function? Try `Interpreter["Color"]/@ StringSplit["red merlot scarlet mahogany currant cherry garnet wine blood blush rose crimson brick sangria candy jam ruby apple berry lipstick"," "]` for example.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to ask `WolframAlpha`, but it can be slow and requires internet connectivity.

```
NearestHTMLColorNames[color_] := Rest[WolframAlpha[
  StringDelete[ToString[ColorConvert[color, "RGB"]], "Color"],
  {{"NearestNamedHTML:ColorData", 1}, "ComputableData"}, 
   PodStates -> {"NearestNamedHTML:ColorData__More"}]][[All, 2]]

NearestHTMLColorNames[RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]
```

> ```
> {"blue", "medium blue", "dark blue", "navy", "dodger blue", "blue violet"}
> ```

This problem was a lot harder than I anticipated! The reason being, the closest distance in Euclidean space does not necessarily mean two colors will look the same.

The idea I has was to look at color's positions in a 3D chromaticity plot and grab the nearest named color to it. The results are *ok*...

```
(* my list of names *)
names = {"white", "tan", "yellow", "orange", "red", "pink", "purple", "blue", "green", "brown", "gray", "black", "turquoise"};

(* find their values *)
colors = Interpreter["Color"][#] -> # & /@ names
```

[image]

```
(* allow lighter and darker variants as well *)
colors = Join @@ (If[MatchQ[#2, "white" | "black"], {#1 -> #2}, 
 {Lighter[#1] -> #2, #1 -> #2, Darker[#1] -> #2}] & @@@ colors)
```

[image]

```
(* find the location of these colors in ChromaticityPlot3D *)
chromaticitylocations = Rule @@@ Reverse /@ 
 Partition[ChromaticityPlot3D[colors[[All, 1]]][[1, 2]], 2] /. 
  Point -> Identity /. c_?ColorQ :> First[Nearest[colors, c]];

(* create our function using Nearest *)
With[{nf = Nearest[chromaticitylocations]},
  NearestColorName[color_] := First[nf[FirstCase[
   ChromaticityPlot3D[color], Point[p_] :> p, _, ∞]]]
]
```

Now we test and see the results aren't terrible.

```
{#, NearestColorName[#]} & /@ RandomColor[40]
```

[image]

We can see the main issue is gray... Probably a simple way to improve this is to use a larger named color bank.

Comment: I wonder if the ChromaticityPlot gives more accurate results than `Nearest[colors, #, DistanceFunction -> "CIE2000"]`? I think the `"gray"` problem might have to do with it being represented as a `GrayLevel`.

Comment: @hftf That's a good question. I played around with different `DistanceFunctions` for `ColorDistance` and `ChromaticityPlot3D` empirically seemed to give the best results. TBH I don't know much about this stuff to give anymore insight :/

Comment: It's okay, I'm colorblind ;)

Comment: @ChipHurst The default ref space for  `ChromaticityPlot` is CIE Yxy, therefore you are clustering using the euclidean distance in that space.

Answer (score 4):

As nobody mentioned it, there is a `"Named"` `ColorData` called `"HTML` that gives (a subset?) of the HTML colors.

```
Short[ColorData["HTML", "ColorRules"], 2]
```

[image: Short[ColorData["HTML", "ColorRules"], 2]]

It takes nothing to build a `NearestFunction` from that.

```
SetAttributes[NearestHTMLColorNames, Listable]

NearestHTMLColorNames[color_?ColorQ] :=
 With[{nf = Nearest[Map[Reverse, ColorData["HTML", "ColorRules"]]]},
  First[nf[color], Missing[]]
 ]
```

And that apply that to a list of colors

```
{#, NearestHTMLColorNames[#]} &@RandomColor[12] // Transpose // Grid
```

[image: color table]